# Python create a list of time slot between start time to end time

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have `start_date`, `end_date`, `from time`, `end time`, and `slot in min` details, I need to create a list of time slot as per following expected

```
import datetime

start_time = '9:00'
end_time = '18:00'
slot_time = 10

# Start date from today to next 5 day
start_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
end_date = datetime.datetime.now().date() + datetime.timedelta(days=5)
```

expected output (*start_date* to *end_date* = total *5 days*)

```
['9:00', '9:10', '9:20', '9:30', '9:40', '9:50', '10:00', '10:10', ..., '17.50', '18:00']
['9:00', '9:10', '9:20', '9:30', '9:40', '9:50', '10:00', '10:10', ..., '17.50', '18:00']
['9:00', '9:10', '9:20', '9:30', '9:40', '9:50', '10:00', '10:10', ..., '17.50', '18:00']
['9:00', '9:10', '9:20', '9:30', '9:40', '9:50', '10:00', '10:10', ..., '17.50', '18:00']
['9:00', '9:10', '9:20', '9:30', '9:40', '9:50', '10:00', '10:10', ..., '17.50', '18:00']
```

My slot time was not fixed it can be 10, 15, 20, 30 minute base on output list of slot create

If my slot time = 15

Expected output (*start_date* to *end_date* = total *5 days*)

```
['9:15', '9:30', '9:45', '10:00', '10:15', ..., '17.45', '18:00']
['9:15', '9:30', '9:45', '10:00', '10:15', ..., '17.45', '18:00']
['9:15', '9:30', '9:45', '10:00', '10:15', ..., '17.45', '18:00']
['9:15', '9:30', '9:45', '10:00', '10:15', ..., '17.45', '18:00']
['9:15', '9:30', '9:45', '10:00', '10:15', ..., '17.45', '18:00']
```

Comment: What's your current output, how it differs from what you want?

Comment: I have no clue how to create this type list.

Comment: Please go through some tutorials then, **post an attempt**. You're basically asking to write code for you.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary If no any idea/clue found then developer what can they do? I am here for getting some idea either for codding way or functional way. So better to avoid this type of your comment and try to help other developer. Hope you understand. Thank you

Comment: That's why tutorials and documentation exists. Questions with no attempt and affort at all clearly make this site look like write-code-for-me.com. This brings the quality of website down. You should have tried something at least and asked question based on that.

Answer (score 7):

You can just iterate over wanted days, then you add nested iteration over wanted hours. For the possibility to compare objects you need to convert strings into `datetime` objects with `strptime` function. Finally, you can get output in arbitrary format with `.strftime` method of `datetime` object.

```
import datetime

start_time = '9:00'
end_time = '18:00'
slot_time = 10

# Start date from today to next 5 day
start_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
end_date = datetime.datetime.now().date() + datetime.timedelta(days=5)

days = []
date = start_date
while date <= end_date:
    hours = []
    time = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time, '%H:%M')
    end = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_time, '%H:%M')
    while time <= end:
        hours.append(time.strftime("%H:%M"))
        time += datetime.timedelta(minutes=slot_time)
    date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    days.append(hours)

for hours in days:
    print(hours)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your problem correctly, you can solve like this:

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

def get_daily_slots(start, end, slot, date):
    # combine start time to respective day
    dt = datetime.combine(date, datetime.strptime(start,"%H:%M").time())
    slots = [dt]
    # increment current time by slot till the end time
    while (dt.time() < datetime.strptime(end,"%H:%M").time()):
        dt = dt + timedelta(minutes=slot)
        slots.append(dt)
    return slots


# Some Dummy values 
start_time = '9:00'
end_time = '15:00'
slot_time = 30
days = 2
start_date = datetime.now().date()

for i in range(days):
    date_required = datetime.now().date() + timedelta(days=1)
    print get_daily_slots(start=start_time, end=end_time, slot=slot_time, date=date_required)
```

Output will look like:

```
[datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31, 9, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31, 9, 30), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31, 10, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31, 10, 30), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31, 11, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31, 11, 30), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31, 12, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31, 12, 30), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31, 13, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31, 13, 30), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31, 14, 30), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31, 15, 0)]
[datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31, 9, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31, 9, 30), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31, 10, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31, 10, 30), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31, 11, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31, 11, 30), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31, 12, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31, 12, 30), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31, 13, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31, 13, 30), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31, 14, 30), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31, 15, 0)]
```

Or you can output as you like.